# android-inapp-billing-v3 consumable product Purchase issue

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchase, product, billing

I am using [android-inapp-billing-v3](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3) for my android app written by kotlin. Now it is ok to make purchase and it goes to a successful page after payment done.
However, the app goes to the successful page directly without any payment and purchase process when same user purchase 2nd time.
I would like to make the app ask for payment every time when user click the pay button. Please kindly help to solve this issue.

```
class ProductActivity : AppCompatActivity(), BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler {


    var ProductID = ""
    var ProductName = ""
    var ProductDes = ""
    var ProductImage = 0
    var ProductPrice = ""
    val googleKey = "fdsfdsfsddfdsfsfdfs"
    lateinit private var bp: BillingProcessor

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product)

        val bundle: Bundle = intent.extras
        ProductID = bundle.getString("ProductID")
        ProductName = bundle.getString("ProductName")
        ProductDes = bundle.getString("ProductDes")
        ProductImage = bundle.getInt("ProductImage")
        ProductPrice = bundle.getString("ProductPrice")


    bp = BillingProcessor(this, googleKey, this)
    bp.consumePurchase(ProductID)

    btn_pay.setOnClickListener {


        bp.purchase(this, ProductID)
        }



    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val internetStatus:Boolean = ConnectivityUtils.isConnected(this)
        if (internetStatus==true) {

        }
        else {
            val msg = getString(R.string.need_internet_for_service)
            finish()
        }
    }


    override fun onBillingInitialized() {

    }

    override fun onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {


    }

    override fun onProductPurchased(productId: String, details: TransactionDetails?) {

        val intent = Intent(this, SearchQponActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("ProductID", ProductID)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun onBillingError(errorCode: Int, error: Throwable?) {

    }



    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        if (bp!=null)
            bp.release()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

Comment: Consume that product immediately after purchase in your `onProductPurchased()`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm using this library for my current application and I used alert dialog to confirm the purchase or subscription.

This library has a lot of bugs (open [issues](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3/issues) page to be sure of that).

I faced a similar problem with this library and end up it with alert dialog and one boolean value `isConfirmedPurchasing`.

In my opinion, it might happen because of:

- You are consuming purchased item in `onCreate`, it doesn't look like a correct way to consume item every opening of the activity
- Looks like this library fires method `onProductPurchased` while initiating, if so then your code inside this score will run.

Hints:

1. Do not consume items in onCreate, do it after the purchasing in `onProductPurchased`
2. You don't need to check if `bp` is null, you created it as late-init otherwise make it nullable
3. Save confirm status in the scope of the `activity` or `shared preferences`
4. Store purchased items somewhere.
5. Make sure you are not using this library in a `fragment`

I created a test application and published that in beta testing, then I refactored your code and used to check how it working (with my keys and ids ofc).

I guess that's what you wanted:

**Data class of your product:**

```
data class MyProduct(
    val id: String,
    val mame: String,
    val des: String,
    val image: Int,
    val price: String
)
```

**Activity:**

```
class ProductActivity : AppCompatActivity(), BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler {

private val googleKey = "your_google_key"
private val keyProductId = "productID"
private var isConfirmedPurchasing = false

private lateinit var bp: BillingProcessor
private lateinit var myProduct: MyProduct

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product)

    bp = BillingProcessor(this, googleKey, this)


    intent.extras?.let { bundle -> 
        with (bundle) {
            myProduct = MyProduct(
                    getString("productID"),
                    getString("productName"),
                    getString("productDes"),
                    getInt("productImage"),
                    getString("productPrice")
            )
        }
    }


    btn_pay.setOnClickListener {
        createAlertDialog(this) {
            isConfirmedPurchasing = true
            purchase(myProduct.id)
        }
    }

}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    bp.release()
    super.onDestroy()
}

override fun onProductPurchased(productId: String, details: TransactionDetails?) {
    isConfirmedPurchasing = false
    bp.consumePurchase(myProduct.id)
    finishPurchaseWorkflow(productId)
}

override fun onBillingInitialized() {
    Log.d("Tag", "BillingProcessor was initialized and it's ready to purchase")
    bp.consumePurchase(myProduct.id)
}

override fun onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
    Log.d("Tag", "requested PRODUCT ID was successfully purchased")
}

override fun onBillingError(errorCode: Int, error: Throwable?) {
    Log.e("Tag", "errorCode: $errorCode, error: $error")
    isConfirmedPurchasing = false
}

private fun purchase(id: String) {
    if (isConfirmedPurchasing) {
        bp.purchase(this, id)
    }
}

private fun finishPurchaseWorkflow(googleProductId: String) {
    val intent = Intent(this, SearchQponActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(keyProductId, googleProductId)
    startActivity(intent)
}

private fun createAlertDialog(
        context: Context,
        title: String? = "Are you sure?",
        message: String? = null,
        buttonPos: String = "Yes",
        buttonNeg: String = "No",
        action: () -> Unit
): AlertDialog {
    return AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setNegativeButton(buttonNeg) { dialog, _ -> dialog.cancel() }
            .setPositiveButton(buttonPos) { dialog, _ -> action(); dialog.cancel() }
            .show()
    }
}
```